# Measure a height of a div using .load

Tags: jquery

I'm using .load to load in an external document. I want the loaded content to animate in, however I don't know how to measure the height of the loaded content.

The div I want to measure in the external document is #box_project2.

The site is live at http://richardhedberg.com/portfolionew/index.html with the height i want to define set to 300px;

```
$('.thumbs2').click(function() {

var idStr = ("project/"+$(this).attr('id'));

    $('#show2').animate({opacity:0},function(){

    $('#close2').fadeIn(500).css({'display': 'block', 'height': '25px'});

    $('#show2').load(idStr,function(){
                $(this).animate({height:'**I WANT TO DEFINE THIS**', opacity:1}, 500, function(){
                });
$.scrollTo('#gohere',300);

    });

});
    });

$('#close2').click(function(){

    $('#close2').fadeOut(300).animate({});
    $('#show2').animate({height: '0px', opacity:0},500, function(){
    $('#show2').children().remove();    
    });
});








 <div id="close2">
 </div> 

 <div id="show2">
 </div>







#close2 {
position:absolute;
width:25px;
height:24px;
background:url(images/graphics/CloseIcon.png);
right:0px;
top:0px;
z-index: 9999;
display: none;
margin-left:-30px;
}

#show2 {
display: block;
height: 0px;
opacity: 1;
margin-left:-30px;
clear:both;
}

#box_project2 {
display:block;
background:#fff;
text-align: left;
clear:both;
height:100%;
}
```

NEW CODE

```
$('.thumbs2').click(function() {

var idStr = ("project/"+$(this).attr('id')) + " #box_project2";

    $('#close2').fadeIn(500).css({'display': 'block', 'height': '25px'});



     $('#show2').load(idStr,function(){
                $(this).slideDown('slow', function() {
                });
                                       $.scrollTo('#gohere',300);


    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate from 0 to the height of the element you can use `slideDown()` http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

```
$('#show2').slideUp().fadeOut();

$('#show2').load(idStr, function() {
   $(this).fadeIn().slideDown();
});
```

Comment: I tried using slideDown (the new code is at the bottom of the old) but it only shows my content without animating, you can see at http://richardhedberg.com/portfolionew/index.html

Comment: You need to set `float:left` for the `#box_project2`. If you have elements that are floating and you want the container to "hold" all them inside you must set float for that element too. For now the only element inside #box_project2 that is not floating is h4 element, so the height of the container (box_project2) is the height of h4. And another thing you have two elements with id="box_project2".

Comment: it works now, i had to rename everything that said "show2" to box_project2, however it doesnt work the first time, so i guess it has something to do with the load. any ideas?

Comment: On your page you have `$('#box_project2').load(...` so you need to set in css `#box_project2 { float:left; }`. SlideDown is working if I set it in Chrome inspector. NOTE: In files like `project/atmotype.html` you have full html you should remove all but the content of `<div id="box_project2">` because you have this element in you index.html. There shouldn't be more then one element with the same id.

Comment: added float:left; and  var idStr = ("project/"+$(this).attr('id')) + " #box_project2"; so it only loads in the div and not the other content. still the same problem, doesnt not work the first time, but after that i works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
idstr.outerHeight(true);
```

This will return the height of the object you are bringing in, and the true will include margins in the height calculation.

Other than that you may just want to use:

```
.slideDown();
```

As suggested which calculates the height and slides for you.

p.s Atmosphere are awesome